# quaternion to euler

Tags: quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I can convert orientation quaternion to Euler angles?
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205696/quaternion-to-euler/) by [Porti77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21654/porti77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2015-03-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/11545/plotprint-rpy-from-quaternion/#17106). It has examples of nodes in roscpp and rospy that do the conversion. If you just want to run the conversion in your code you can strip out the relevant function calls.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2015-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This might help too, a quaternion <-> Euler converter: http://quat.zachbennett.com/

---

Originally posted by [Pat](https://answers.ros.org/users/20010/pat/) with karma: 62 on 2015-04-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1